# jqGrid multi grouping 2nd level does not appear

Tags: jqgrid

I've been trying to make the multi grouping feature of jqGrid to work, but I'm only getting the first level grouping:

[image]

There should be another group. Here's the source code:

```
$('#grdData').jqGrid({
    url: 'Default.aspx?method=GetGridData',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Exchange', 'Market', 'Security Name', '', ''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'exchange', index: 'exchange', width: 100, align: 'center' },
        { name: 'market', index: 'market', width: 100, align: 'center' },
        { name: 'secname', index: 'secname', width: 200 },
        { name: 'remino', index: 'remino' },
        { name: 'clino', index: 'clino' }
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    pager: '#pgrGrid',
    sortname: 'exchange',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['remino', 'clino'],
        groupColumnShow: [false, false],
        groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>', '{0}'],
        groupCollapse: false,
        groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
        groupDataSorted: true
    }
 });
```

The clino group does not appear, I checked the response json and I think it's ok. Also, when I set groupColumnShow to 'true', 'true' - both grouping columns show in the header.

Comment: can you post your server response -- why do you have blank column names ' ',' '?

Comment: @Ryan_Rubin, did you get an answer to this? I am getting the same error. If I try to group by either field, it works. If I try to group by both fields, only the first grouping is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be sorted by 'remino' and 'clino'. Then it will work.